# Error is attached to wrong input field when a form object involves two models with the same attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, activerecord, error-handling

I'm working on a form object that involves updating a `User` record with it's many associated models like `Address` and `Phone` via nested attributes.

Both `Address` and `Phone` models have a `number` attribute, so I name each HTML input and form object attribute differently for each one.

```
<%= simple_form_for @user_form, method: :patch do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :number %>
  <%= f.input :phone %>

<% end %>
```

controller:

```
  def edit
    @user_form = UserForm.new(@user)
  end

  def update
    @user_form = UserForm.new(@user, update_params)
    if @customer_update.save
      redirect_to :users_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def update_params
    params.require(:user_form).permit(:number, :phone)
  end
```

Simplified form object:

```
class UserForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks

  attr_accessor :number
                :phone
  

  attr_reader :user

  validate :validate_children


  def initialize(user, update_params = nil)
    @user = user

    super(update_params)
  end

  def save
    user.assign_attributes(user_params)
    return false if invalid?

    user.save
  end  
  
  
  def user_params
    {}.tap do |p|
      p[:address_attributes] = {number: number}
      p[:phone_attributes] = {number: phone}
    end.compact
  end


  def validate_children
    promote_errors(user.associated_model.errors) if associated_model.invalid?
  end


  def promote_errors(child_errors)
    child_errors.each do |attribute, message|
      errors.add(attribute, message)
    end
  end
end
```

I delegate validation to the actual `Address` and `Phone` models where there is a

```
validates :number, presence: true
```

so if validations on either models kick in, the errors are promoted up to the form object and displayed on the invalid input field.

```
@user_form.errors.keys
=> [:"phone.number", :number]

@user_form.errors.full_messages
=> ["Number can't be blank"]
```

The problem is that if for example the `:phone` field is left blank when the form is submited, because the actual attribute that is invalid is the `Phone` `number`, the error is displayed in the `:number` input field in my form, or in other words the `Phone` `number` error is rendered in the `Address` `number` field because the form input is called the same (`f.input :number`).

Is there a way to change that or promote the errors differently so this doesn't happen?  The code above is obviously dumbed down, let me know if specifics are needed.

Comment: In the end, the most reasonable workaround was to bypass simple_form error rendering by not using simple_form inputs for those fields, and rendering errors manually for each of them (checking if `form_object.errors.full_messages_for(:key)` is present.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a lot of unnecessary complexity.

The way you would typically set this up in Rails is to use `fields_for` (and the SF wrapper `simple_fields_for`):

```
<%= form_with(model: @user) do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for(:phone) do |phone_fields| %>
    <pre><%= phone_fields.object.errors.full_messages.inspect %></pre>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.fields_for(:number) do |number_fields| %>
    <pre><%= number_fields.object.errors.full_messages.inspect %></pre>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

These methods yield a form builder and calling `object` gets the model instance wrapped by the form builder. This makes it easy to either display the errors together or per attribute and get it right - this is especially true if you're dealing with a one to many or many to many instead of one to one.